# Is there a default Eclipse application or product when starting Eclipse application?

Tags: eclipse

If I don't pass `-application` or `-product` argument to an Eclipse application, then how does the Eclipse application choose which application/product to run? Is there a default product/application defined for an Eclipse application?

I am using an Eclipse application which has about 10 applications defined via the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension and about 5 products defined in various plugins. The startup batch file supplied by the application developer does not include `-application` or `-product` command line argument nor is specified in the application's .ini file.

In such case, which application/product is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is normally specified in the `config.ini` file in the application `configuration` directory.

For example the config.ini for one of my RCPs is

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Sun Dec 11 11:34:31 GMT 2022
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2
eclipse.p2.profile=DefaultProfile
eclipse.product=greg.synch.e4.rcp.product
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.4.200.v20221111-1340.jar@1\:start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.18.200.v20221116-1324.jar
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.2.800.v20221116-1440.jar
```

The `eclipse.application` and `eclipse.product` entries specify the application and product.

The `config.ini` is often generated automatically from data in the `.product` file by the Tycho build.

Comment: Thanks. This explains it. I was looking in the <Application>.ini file not the config.ini file.